# Why am I not getting desired Nav bar in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

The Nav bar I tried to implement is different from what I am getting.
[Inverse Nav bar I wanted to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoUqY.png)

But 
[The result I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygbDj.png)

The code is:

```js
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Landing page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the closest appearance by using below code.
On large screen the links will appear as whole. The links will be collapsed on small screen.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Website Name</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Page 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are including Boostrap 4. But your code is for Bootstrap 3. 
This should do approximately what you want in Bootstrap 4.

```css
.active{
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home </a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found in the documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Landing page</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
           <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 1</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 2</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 3</a>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```